# Sign In with Twitter is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, twitter

In my Web application I have integrated login with twitter option.This feature worked correctly, but last 2 weeks it gives me error : Getting (401) Unauthorized https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

If I already login with twitter in other tab and When I try to login with twitter in application, It works correctly, But if I not already login with twitter, and try to login with my application, then it gives me unauthorized error(401).

help..